# i want to multiply a character L to identity matrix in c#

Tags: c#

```
 for (int row = 0; row < SS; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < SS; col++)
            {
                    identity[row, col] = (row == col) ? 1 : 0;

                Response.Write(identity[row, col] + " ");
            }
            Response.Write("<br/>"); 
        }
```

now my output is 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1

i want to get output as L 0 0 0 L 0 0 0 L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare your array as type string(or char) and try this:

```
identity[row, col] = (row == col) ? "L" : "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

identity[row, col] = (row == col) ? "L": "0";